# How would a war in open fields be fought?

Tags: warfare

Make it with WWI technology.  If two sides of about equal military capability were to start fighting one another on a front with overall flat grass, what can they do to try to one-up the other side?  Would that even be possible, or would the front remain generally unmoved?  I already have a few ideas of my own, but I'd like to get as many forms of combat into this as possible.  Thanks. :^)

Comment: WWI was in what was an open field. Mostly the Eastern front, and the middle East.

Comment: WWI was largely fought on open grassland. It's called the [European Plain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Plain) and it runs from the West Coast of France to the Ural Mountains in Russia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to make me go to trenches, and I said "No, no, no!"**

I'm assuming your question is asking "How would WW1 have been fought without trenches?" The original goal of the Von Schlieffen plan was to do just this, avoiding the attrition-style trench warfare that characterized the end of the US civil war. The effort was to use blitzkrieg-like tactics to overwhelm the enemy and always have more force at the battle. Unfortunately, roads and vehicles of this era weren't quite ready for it. The plan did come reasonably close to succeeding, but once it stalled, the whole plan was vulnerable to counterattack, and degenerated into the very attrition warfare that was feared.

Most of the fighting that went on at this time OUTSIDE of the big battles in Europe was mobile, relying on lighter weapons and mobility. There was a heavy emphasis on navy, because that let you fill in the logistics you couldn't do so well on land.

Your scenario would involve either improvements in transportation, logistics from the sea, or better surprise of underprepared forces. It would look like WW2 but with lighter, older vehicles. Machine guns and cannons take time to set up, so making these more mobile would hurt your scenario (definitely machine guns; good cannons might help break defenses). The primary weapon would be mobs of guys with bolt-action rifles overwhelming their enemies with numbers. Otherwise, there would be a strong pressure to dig in, fortify, and pour bullets into exposed human flesh like the slaughter of the civil war proved.

Tanks were designed to break the stalemate of WW1, and mobile armored trucks wouldn't need to deal with barbed wire and trenches. Armored cars and APCs would let you have some of that "combined arms" benefit but still be inside the achievable tech of WW1. Actual tanks of this era were probably too slow for the battles you're looking for. Cavalry would still be prominent, but a little out-of-date for the mobility needed for a large, WW1 mobility war.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  This is exactly what I'm looking for.